# does append "a+" automatically put cursor to the end

Tags: c, file-io

I want to open a file with c then add some content to it and close it. I just want to know **a+** in **fopen** automatically navigates to the last character of file.

Comment: Just read the documentation of "fopen", e.g. here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

Comment: If you don't like the manual you could do something like `ftell(f,0,SEEK_CUR);`

Comment: This question could be improved by writing two programs, one which uses "a+" and one which uses "a" and compare the results of running each program. Then you could submit it to SO if you want as an "answer your own question" question

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does.

Why don't you try, or read the manual ?

Here it is :

```
   r      Open text file for reading.  The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.

   r+     Open for reading and writing.  The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.

   w      Truncate file to zero length or create text file for writing.  The stream is positioned at the  beginning  of  the
          file.

   w+     Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does not exist, otherwise it is truncated.  The stream is
          positioned at the beginning of the file.

   a      Open for appending (writing at end of file).  The file is created if it does not exist.  The stream is  positioned
          at the end of the file.

   a+     Open  for  reading and appending (writing at end of file).  The file is created if it does not exist.  The initial
          file position for reading is at the beginning of the file, but output is always appended to the end of the file.
```

Comment: Answering this question does the user no favour. He should learn to read documentation first, or do a simple web search before he is asking the question here.

Comment: This is true, but hey, that's a little what stack overflow is about... at least people web-searching will find that.